# Increase maximum outgoing attachment size

Tags: email, active-sync, attachments

I'm looking for a way to increase the maximum attachment size for outgoing email in the default email app for Exchange / "corporate" email.

e.g. I'm on local Wifi and it won't let me send a 9MB video, which is just plain lame.

While I'm at it, I'd love to also increase the maximum size for App downloads when on 3G.  I have a high-speed dataplan with a 6GB limit, and it's frustrating to have my phone tell me something is "too big" to download.  My carrier isn't saving any bandwidth; it just forces me to use workarounds like tethering.

Open to rooting or any other hacks that will do the trick.  I have control of the Exchange (2003) server if the setting must be tweaked there.

Comment: If there's no easy way to adjust, then whichever genius at Google dictated these arbitrary limits should be flogged.